# Use dynamic names for CJ in data.table

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I want to use `CJ` with a flexible number of columns with flexible names, for example

```
J = 3
temp = CJ(paste0('Q', 1) = 0:100)
if(J > 1){
  for(j in 2:J){
    temp = CJ(temp,paste0('Q', j) = 0:100))
  }
}
```

For arbitrary J.

Where the output is:

```
CJ(Q1 = 0:100, Q2 = 0:100, Q3 = 0:100)


          Q1  Q2  Q3
      1:   0   0   0
      2:   0   0   1
      3:   0   0   2
      4:   0   0   3
      5:   0   0   4
     ---            
1030297: 100 100  96
1030298: 100 100  97
1030299: 100 100  98
1030300: 100 100  99
1030301: 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic case for `do.call`:

```
temp = do.call(CJ, replicate(J, 0:100, simplify = FALSE))
setnames(temp, paste0('Q', 1:J))
temp
#           Q1  Q2  Q3
#       1:   0   0   0
#       2:   0   0   1
#       3:   0   0   2
#       4:   0   0   3
#       5:   0   0   4
#      ---            
# 1030297: 100 100  96
# 1030298: 100 100  97
# 1030299: 100 100  98
# 1030300: 100 100  99
# 1030301: 100 100 100
```

It's possible to construct this in one line using `setNames` and `lapply` instead of `replicate`, but much less readable IMO. `setnames` is almost instantaneous so there's no efficiency concern.